# How to count based on unique embedded array values

Tags: mongodb

My collection:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "type" : "A", "types" : [ "type1://asfasd", "type2://xcvxcv" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "type" : "B", "types" : [ "type1://xcv" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "type" : "C", "types" : [ "type2://aewqqwe" ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "type" : "D", "types" : [ "type2://xcxc" ] }
```

I want the end result to count and tell me:

```
type1 -> 2 (because there are total of 2 documents that has type1)
type2 -> 3 (because there are total of 3 documents that has type2)
```

Comment: Does all of your documents `types` values prefixes (`type1`, `type2`) are of constant length (here 5)? Or there are prefixes of different length (like `http` and `https`)?

Comment: No there are not in a fixed size (can be type1://, othertype3://). I suppose a minimum of 3 letters before the :// is OK (if substr is planned here?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With map-reduce you can use a regex to *extract* and *group* the documents based on the string you want i.e. type1, type2, type69 etc.

As far as I know, you can't use a regex with aggregation pipeline and group stage.

Therefore, in the map phase, iterate over the types array, use a regex to extract your strings i.e. type1, type2, than emit this string as key with a value of 1.
In the reduce phase, all values with the same key will be in one list, than you just count the length of the list:

```
var map = function map(){
    for (type in this.types){
        var str = this.types[type];
        var rx = /type\d+/;
        var match = str.match(rx);
        emit (match[0], 1);
    }
};

var reduce = function(key, values){
    return values.length
};


db.runCommand({"mapReduce":"collection", map:map, reduce:reduce, out:{replace:"collection2"}})
```

Ex output on your data:

```
{ "_id" : "type1", "value" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "type2", "value" : 3 }
```